# Why was I blocked from chat for asking users to complete a survey for my computing GCSE homework?

Tags: discussion, chat, stack-overflow-developer-survey

Why was I blocked from chat for asking users to complete a survey for my computing GCSE homework? I gave them a link to the survey, and they deleted it, so i reposted it and they marked me as spam, so i took it to another room, and now i cannot go on chat.

Comment: I'm sorry, we're currently only accepting questions about hats.  Can you please rephrase your question to include hats? </joke>

Comment: // Deletes question as it contains offending link.

Comment: It was intended to be a joke, I haven't voted to delete your question. You need to lean how Meta works; there's more jokes here than you'll ever see on SO.

Comment: ...a moderator just deleted your link, and you reposted it in a comment? I get being confused and wanting to ask about policy and such, but obstinately reposting something over and over when it's obviously controversial if not outright unwanted is not a good way to get people on your side.

Comment: Because it's a spam. hth

Comment: I can give you spam. how about log off prevention and infinite IE 4 browser windows opening and 100 page word documents saving inifinitely? thats spamming.

Comment: That's malware.

Comment: @deep: That's not spam! But no, you can't. Nobody has IE 4 installed anymore.

Comment: @deep There's really no need to keep an argument going. You've gotten your explanation now, next time just ask before you post such an "invitation". And let's keep it at that.

Comment: fine the current browser, anyway spamming is just sending REPETITIVE messages to someone, not THREE

Comment: You came to our room and dumped a link that nobody was interested in. So a room owner binned your message. Then you proceeded to dump it **again** and **again**. So I took the effort to clean up the mess and binned the rest of the them. At the same time, a bunch of us flagged your links as spam since you showed no signs of stopping.

Comment: THAT is an exaggeration. i posted it thrice.

Comment: After that, you went to the C# room and dumped your link - which was promptly flagged-deleted.

Comment: BEcause your room wasnt helping and i need to hand it in TOMMORROW, and its something that requires outside input.

Comment: @deep Once again, now you know: ask before you post. If they are not receptive, that's just too bad. Move on. Your homework deadlines, no matter how important to you, are not really of importance to the visitors of the chat room.

Comment: *goes into lesson
 teacher" deep have you got the results" 
me:"no, because the people on S.O. are too lazy and weren't interested"
If you were a techer what would you say?

Comment: @deep "Don't blame the people on SO. It is up to you as my student to find participants for your survey. The unwillingness of a single community is no excuse".

Comment: Been on Y!A, FB, G+, the phone, txting,twitter,S.O., how many results? 10/150 minimum

Comment: That's not SO's fault, though. Maybe find more willing participants some other way

Comment: @deep That's a shame, but it's your problem, not ours.

Comment: @simchona Such as?

Comment: It's not my homework.

Comment: @deep, sorry you got treated that way.  It certainly wasn't spam.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not an apology i want, its results

Comment: @LanceRoberts The link itself may not be spam. But repeatedly posting it multiple times when it is clear that the room does not welcome it ***is*** spam.

Comment: Fine. I'm Sorry for the trouble i caused. I give up this pointless argument, next time i do a survey i'll ask first, o.k.? but what about the survey at hand? anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @deep I admit that the room owner who initially deleted your first link came down a bit hard on you. (that's pretty typical of him) Personally, I don't delete first-time drive-by-links. So if that sent the wrong message. I apologize, but for the future, pay attention to the responses of other users. If they are objecting, or are simply ignoring you, it's usually a sign that your link is either not interesting, or not wanted.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You were **automatically** suspended from chat because your link kept getting deleted. It was a 2-hour suspension. In the future, if they delete your link, it usually means they don't want it there, and posting it again is not a good way to solve the problem.

Comment: I reposted it once, as they might have accidentally deleted it, i wasnt spamming.

Comment: @deep: A good way to go about it is to just *ask* in the channel if people there would be willing to take your survey *first* (then post the link if they agree), rather than just jumping in and posting a link.

Comment: Thanks, will do, do i just have to wait out the ban though?

Comment: Yes, it's only a couple hours, of which you've killed 15 minutes already.

Comment: K. thanks for that. bye!

Comment: You reposted it far more than once, and we were quite unambiguous as to that we did not want you.

Comment: i posted it thrice max.

Comment: @deep Ah, so you admit that you lied in your question, and then lied in the comments, all the while understating the number of times you reposted the link.

Comment: @meagar 4 times in the C++ room. Once in the C# room. By the time I went to the C# room to check out the burst of flags, the first of the links had already been flag-deleted and he was banned from posting.

Comment: I went over chat, i was 3 times for the actual link in the c++ room and i lied in my question?