# Inviting chat users to participate in external surveys

Tags: discussion, chat

A user [posted an invitation to a survey in a site’s chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56035066#56035066).

Posting surveys *as questions* is not ok on SE sites for pretty obvious reasons. **But what’s the official policy for chat rooms?**

Comment: Depends on the chatroom and how much of a scam your "survey" looks.

Comment: If it was an obvious scam, I‘d know what to do ;-) But it’s by a regular user and I’d appreciate some official guidance, also for legitimate requests, e.g. someone doing scientific research.

Comment: The safest thing is: add it to your user profile and then say in chat something like *I have an survey linked from my user profile that might be of interest for the regulars here*. You're free to advertise your about me, and almost anything goes in there.

Comment: @rene while that is certainly true, I think the OP is more looking towards advice as: This got posted, what should we do with it? In this case I think this was the best way to reach a relevant sample pool for the survey author. Not that it would be a very random draw, but okay. If your chatroom has explicit rules against these sort of posts I'd say you'd delete it, otherwise it seems fine to me.

Comment: See [this](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1586/sharing-interesting-information) post, it seems fairly similar.  Note that the first two comments say, "*We could place them in chat*"...so maybe it's okay, depending on the room rules.

Comment: @Luuklag I somehow missed that the OP isn't the same user who posted the survey. And on closer inspection it looks like that invite is replicated to new rooms. Which personally dislike.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159730/why-was-i-blocked-from-chat-for-asking-users-to-complete-a-survey-for-my-computi.

Comment: Well, survey is the same as self promotion, so the answers in the dupe fits your case as well.

Comment: This question is a [bit of this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44021/282094), and a [bit of that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169927/282094) - leaving closed.